# Async/Await Node-Postgres Queries Within ForEach Loops

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, foreach, node-postgres

EDIT: I'm using node v8.0.0

I just started learning how to access SQL databases with node-postgres, and I'm having a little bit of trouble accessing multiple databases to collect the data in a work able format, particularly with executing multiple queries within forEach loops. After a few tries, I'm trying async/await, but I get the following error:

```
await client.connect()
  ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

When I tried using a pool or calling .query sequentially, I would get something along the lines of

```
1
[]
could not connect to postgres Error: Connection terminated
```

Here is an abbreviated version of my code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const moment = require('moment');
const _ = require('lodash');
const turf = require('@turf/turf');

const connString = // connection string
var collected = []
const CID = 300
const snaptimes = // array of times
var counter=0;
const client = new Client(connString);

function createArray(i,j) {
     // return array of i arrays of length j
}

await client.connect()

snaptimes.forEach(function(snaptime){
  var info = {}; // an object of objects
  // get information at given snaptime from database 1
  const query1 = // parametrized query selecting two columns from database 1
  const result1 = await client.query(query1, [CID,snaptime]);
  var x = result1.rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     // store data from database 1 into info
     // each row is an object with two fields
  }

  // line up subjects on the hole
  const query2 = // parametrized query grabbing JSON string from database 2
  const result2 = await client.query(query2, [CID,snaptime]);
  const raw = result2.rows[0].JSON_col;
  const line = createArray(19,0); // an array of 19 empty arrays
  for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
     // parse JSON object and record data into line 
  }

  // begin to collect data
  var n = 0;
  var g = 0;
  // walk down the line
  for (var i = 18; i > 0; i--) {
    // if no subjects are found at spot i, do nothing, except maybe update g
    if ((line[i] === undefined || line[i].length == 0) && g == 0){
      g = i;
    } else if (line[i] !== undefined && line[i].length != 0) {
      // collect data for each subject if subjects are found
      line[i].forEach(function(subject){
        const query 3 = // parametrized query grabbing data for each subject 
        const result3 = await client.query(query3,[CID,subject,snaptime]);
        x = result3.rows;
        const y = moment(x[0].end_time).diff(moment(snaptime),'minutes');
        var yhat = 0;
        // the summation over info depends on g
        if (g===0){
          for (var j = i; j <= 18; j++){
            yhat = moment.duration(info[j].field1).add(yhat,'m').asMinutes();
          }
        } else {
          for (var j = i; j <= 18; j++){
            if (i<j && j<g+1) {
              yhat = moment.duration(info[j].field2).add(yhat,'m').asMinutes();
            } else {
              yhat = moment.duration(info[j].field1).add(yhat,'m').asMinutes();
            }
          }
        }
        collected.push([y,yhat,n,i]);
      });
    }
    n+=line[i].length;
    g=0;
  }
  // really rough work-around I once used for printing results after a forEach of queries
  counter++;
  if (counter===snaptimes.length){
    console.log(counter);
    console.log(collected);
    client.end(); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by your forEach callback not being `async`:

```
snaptimes.forEach(function(snaptime){
```

should be:

```
snaptimes.forEach(async function (snaptime) {
```

for the `await` to be recognizable at all.

Keep in mind that an `async` function returns immediately and it returns a promise that gets eventually resolved by `return` statements of the `async` function (or rejected with uncaught exceptions raised inside the `async` function).

But also make sure your Node version supports `async`/`await`:

- Since Node 7.6 it can be used with no `--harmony` flag.
- In Node 7.x before 7.6 you have to use the `--harmony` flag.
- It was not available in Node before 7.0.

See: http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions

Also note that you can use `await` **only** inside of functions declared with the `async` keyword. If you want to use it in the top level of your script or module then you need to wrap it in an immediately invoked function expression:

```
// cannot use await here
(async () => {
  // can use await here
})();
// cannot use await here
```

Example:

```
const f = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('x'), 500));

let x = await f();
console.log(x);
```

prints:

```
$ node t1.js 
/home/rsp/node/test/prom-async/t1.js:3
let x = await f();
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

but this:

```
const f = () => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r('x'), 500));

(async () => {
  let x = await f();
  console.log(x);
})();
```

prints:

```
$ node t2.js 
x
```

after 0.5s delay, as expected.

On versions of Node that don't support `async`/`await` the first (incorrect) example will print:

```
$ ~/opt/node-v6.7.0/bin/node t1.js 
/home/rsp/node/test/prom-async/t1.js:3
let x = await f();
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and the second (correct) example will print a different error:

```
$ ~/opt/node-v6.7.0/bin/node t2.js 
/home/rsp/node/test/prom-async/t2.js:3
(async () => {
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

It's useful to know because Node versions that don't support `async`/`await` will not give you a meaningful error like "async/await not supported" or something like that, unfortunately.

Comment: Putting async before any function calling await cleared up the issue very nicely. However, when I try adding more snaptimes to the the snaptime array on which the first forEach is called, I either get `Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly` or `Error: read ECONNRESET`. Going off of print statements, these errors occur immediately on query1. Moving client.end() to after the forEach loop just causes the code to not run

Comment: @HansyPiou When you're using async/await then I would recommend using `for (let snaptime of snaptimes) { ... }` instead of `snaptimes.forEach(function (snaptime) { ... });` because that way you will not call another functions and it will be easier to synchronize the iteration steps.

Comment: The whole things working great now! Using for() loops meant I had to wrap them all into a larger (async) function, but that ultimately cleared up issues with node-postgres since I could connect the client before collecting the data and close it when I was done. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you should use `async` block outside like:

```
async function() {
  return await Promise.resolve('')
}
```

And it is default supported after node 7.6.0. Before 7.6.0, you should use `--harmony` option to work for it.

`node -v` first to check your version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't know enough about async-await just yet. don't worry, it's actually quite easy; but you need to read the documentation to be able to use that stuff.

More to the point, the problem with your code is that you can only `await` inside `async` functions; you're doing that outside of *any* function.

First of all, here's the solution that is closest to the code you wrote:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const moment = require('moment');
const _ = require('lodash');
const turf = require('@turf/turf');

const connString = // connection string
var collected = []
const CID = 300
const snaptimes = // array of times
var counter=0;
const client = new Client(connString);

function createArray(i,j) {
    // return array of i arrays of length j
}

async function processSnaptime (snaptime) {
    var info = {}; // an object of objects
    // get information at given snaptime from database 1
    const query1 = // parametrized query selecting two columns from database 1
    const result1 = await client.query(query1, [CID,snaptime]);
    var x = result1.rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      // store data from database 1 into info
      // each row is an object with two fields
    }

    // line up subjects on the hole
    const query2 = // parametrized query grabbing JSON string from database 2
    const result2 = await client.query(query2, [CID,snaptime]);
    const raw = result2.rows[0].JSON_col;
    const line = createArray(19,0); // an array of 19 empty arrays
    for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
      // parse JSON object and record data into line
    }

    // begin to collect data
    var n = 0;
    var g = 0;
    // walk down the line
    for (var i = 18; i > 0; i--) {
      // if no subjects are found at spot i, do nothing, except maybe update g
      if ((line[i] === undefined || line[i].length == 0) && g == 0){
        g = i;
      } else if (line[i] !== undefined && line[i].length != 0) {
        // collect data for each subject if subjects are found
        line[i].forEach(function(subject){
          const query 3 = // parametrized query grabbing data for each subject
          const result3 = await client.query(query3,[CID,subject,snaptime]);
          x = result3.rows;
          const y = moment(x[0].end_time).diff(moment(snaptime),'minutes');
          var yhat = 0;
          // the summation over info depends on g
          if (g===0){
            for (var j = i; j <= 18; j++){
              yhat = moment.duration(info[j].field1).add(yhat,'m').asMinutes();
            }
          } else {
            for (var j = i; j <= 18; j++){
              if (i<j && j<g+1) {
                yhat = moment.duration(info[j].field2).add(yhat,'m').asMinutes();
              } else {
                yhat = moment.duration(info[j].field1).add(yhat,'m').asMinutes();
              }
            }
          }
          collected.push([y,yhat,n,i]);
        });
      }
      n+=line[i].length;
      g=0;
    }
    // really rough work-around I once used for printing results after a forEach of queries
    counter++;
    if (counter===snaptimes.length){
      console.log(counter);
      console.log(collected);
    }
}

async function run () {
  for (let snaptime of snaptimes) {
    await processSnaptime(snaptime);
  }
}

/* to run all of them concurrently:
function run () {
  let procs = [];
  for (let snaptime of snaptimes) {
    procs.push(processSnaptime(snaptime));
  }
  return Promise.all(procs);
}
*/

client.connect().then(run).then(() => client.end());
```

`client.connect` returns a promise and I use `then` to call `run` once it's resolved. When *that* part is over, `client.end()` can be called safely.

`run` is an `async` function, therefore it can use `await` to make the code more readable. The same goes for `processSnaptime`.

Of course I can't actually *run* your code, so I can only hope I didn't make any mistakes.